# Mail.app (Yosemite) sometimes doesn't sync Exchange Inbox

Tags: mail.app, macos, exchange-activesync

I have intermittent issues where Mail.app on Yosemite (10.10.1) sometimes fails to sync my Exchange Inbox. From home, I use OWA, and I see a different view there, with a number of conversations that don't show up in Mail.app. When I move the conversation to a different folder, it does seem to be synced correctly.

Anyone has seen this before, or know a work around to sync better?

@edit by DO:
I've a similar issue, I think this happens specially to mails in conversations. These are the errors I'm getting:

```
02/12/2014 22:55:08.206 Mail[21335]: Stream 0x600000911820 is sending an event before being opened
02/12/2014 22:55:08.384 Mail[21335]: Error: 500 The e-mail address cannot be found.
02/12/2014 22:55:08.511 Mail[21335]: EWS fetchRootFolderId: received an error: 234
```

Comment: What does connection doctor (Window Menu) show for the status of Exchange server? Also, have you opened the activity window to watch for the status of communications to OWA. If the server is having problems, the sync could be not complete yet.